# Serving simple image with App Engine django patch?

Tags: python, django, app-engine-patch

How the heck do i serve a simple img without all that [MediaGenerator](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/wiki/MediaGenerator) nonsense, in Django on App Engine?
I am using app engine patch.

I got layout like this:

- django_app_engine_project_folder

  - my_app

Where should my folder for my media be? In my_app? Or do I put everything in the top media folder?

I want to do something like this in my HTML template...

```
<img src="/site_media/my_image.jpg" />
```

Note that **/media** prefix is already beign used for admin media.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems that using app.yaml works out:

```
- url: /my_app/media/
  static_dir: my_app/media
```

Which allows me to refer to image a.jpg in folder my_app/media with a url like:

```
<img src="/my_app/media/a.jpg" />
```